# Build multiple projects/repositories with one build definition VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using VSTS for my OPA5 Tests, so all works for one project. For this I created a Build for these Projects i wanted to test. 
But if I want to test all projects, do I need to create a build for all Project or is there a solution to build all projects with one build definition?

The build should do always the same things, saved in a YAML File.

I have seen thats is possible to do builds with difficult branches but not with difficult repositories.

So has anyone a solution for this or is it impossible at the moment?

Comment: Does the answer helps you solve the problem? If yes, can you mark the answer? And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You just need to clone another git repositories at the beginning of the build.

So you can add a **PowerShell task** as the first task and execute `git clone` command.

And If you are using YAML file, just add the script to execute the PowerShell task.

Besides, you can also refer the post [VSTS build from multiple repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571664/vsts-build-from-multiple-repositories/49571939#49571939).