# Azure Devops - Multiple repositories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have code in two github repositories that I would like to build and run in the same build pipeline.

Does anybody know if it's possible to clone/pull more than one repo during the 'get sources' step?

Comment: This question is very similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571664/vsts-build-from-multiple-repositories

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS build from multiple repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571664/vsts-build-from-multiple-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

In Azure DevOps, a pipeline is only associated with a single repository, by default.  However, there are options to include code from other Git repositories in to the build:

1. Add Command Line task and execute git clone with a PAT in the pipeline
2. Add the 2nd repository as a submodule to your primary repository.  Make sure to check the 'checkout submodules' checkbox under 'Get sources' in the classic editor.
3. Build each repository separately and use a RELEASE pipeline to bring them together as below:

From the left menu, choose "Releases" under the "Pipeline" group. (as of 14th Oct 2019).
You will be able to add multiple artifacts to the pipeline by clicking on '+ Add'.
The screenshot below shows 3 different sources.  A docker image in Azure Container Registry, A build that has output artifacts & a GitHub repository.

[image: Artifacts for the Pipeline]

All the artifacts get copied to the build agent at run time in their own folders:

[image: Azure DevOps - Release Pipeline]

Comment: This will unfortunately not solve the questions, as he asked for the build pipeline. As of now, I couldn't find any way to add another repo to the BUILD pipeline.

Comment: @Plattenschieber:  Thanks for the feedback.  Tried  again.